# How to read NMEA message using GPSD?

Tags: gps, file-geodatabase, ubuntu, data-collection

I am trying to read NMEA messages via GPSD (http://www.catb.org/gpsd/), but I do not know how to do that.

I have a GPS antenna which connects to the u-blox M8 GNSS Evaluation Kit Timin (https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/evk-8evk-m8) and this Kit is connected to Ubuntu laptop.

In the Terminal window, when I type "lsusb", it shows me the device successfully connect (for example: Bus 001 Device 036: ID 1546:01a8 U-Blox AG)

As I know when the GPS receive a signal, it should be putting NMEA messages out in each port, and should be mounted by TTYACM0.

The Laptop also installed NTP (Network Time Protocol)

My question is:

- what does the GPSD do with that?
- what can  the GPSD log these messages?
- How to confiure GPSD to set NMEA messages from the u-blox USB port?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question.